# Getting Annotation selection using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, select

I have annotations stored in mxd document, when I select some annotation, I tried to get the selection through graphics selection, so I always get the rectangle of the dataframe (because I'm working on a axPageLayoutControl), and when I use feature selection I get nothing; so  none of them return the annotation selection.

How could I get the annotation selection in ArcObjects?

I'm using ArcObjects 10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are stored in the Graphicscontainer of BasicGraphicsLayer, so this code get the selection of Annotations, it works for me :)

```
IGraphicsContainerSelect graContSel = (IGraphicsContainerSelect)mapDocument.ActiveView.FocusMap.BasicGraphicsLayer;

m_enumElem = graContSel.SelectedElements; 

m_enumElem.Reset();

elem = m_enumElem.Next();

ITextElement txel = elem as ITextElement;
```

Comment: +1 However, I've found [IEnumElement](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEnumElement_Interface/00120000047z000000/) will often not start at the beginning unless I explicitly call Reset().